# i want to read FTP file using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

i want to read FTP file using Apache camel but my requirement is like that to pick all files around 4-5 files and process them but my question is that how can i pick files only for specific date example i want to pick all file which is created today leave yesterday file.

how can i write code to pick files from FTP using apache camel with filtration on dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement your custom filter and ask camel to process only the files that satisfy the filter

Eg:

```
public class DateFilter<T> implements GenericFileFilter<T> {
    public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long todayInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();
        return file.getLastModified() >= todayInMillis;
    }
}
```

Define the FileFilter as a bean

```
<bean id="dateFilter" class="com.something.DateFilter"/>
```

Use the above filter in your route

```
from("ftp://someuser@someftpserver.com?password=secret&amp;filter=#dateFilter")
   .to("somedestination")
```

Documentation [here](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html#FTP-Filterusingorg.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter)